# What is known about lower etale cohomology of unirational varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, birational-geometry, positive-characteristic, brauer-groups

Which information is currently known about $H^1_{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}_l)$ and  $H^2_{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}_l)$, where $X$ is a smooth unirational variety over an algebraically closed field of finite characterstic $p\neq l$? Actually, I am interested in the case where $X$ is a quotient of a rational variety $Y$ by a free action of a finite group (whose order is prime to $p$). Does the situation differ much from the complex variety case; are there any examples where it does?

Certainly, my question is closely related to (the torsion) of $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ and to the Brauer group of $X$.

Comment: If you want your varieties to behave like in characteristic $0$, it's probably better to say *separably* unirational. In positive characteristic there are all sorts of 'strange' unirational varieties; for example there exist unirational K3 surfaces. Maybe this doesn't matter for your question, but it seems that you're thinking about the separable case anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the $H^2$, for $X$ a smooth projective rationally chain connected variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\ell \in k^\ast$,  it follows from 
 Theorem 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05735 that

> > $$\mathrm{NS}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} = \mathrm{H}^2_{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(1))$$